# How to "fill" hole in sink countertop

Tags: kitchen-counters, hole-repair

We have a countertop of what feels like solid stone and I am guessing is some kind of engineered quartz:
[image]

Is it possible to "fill in" a hole that has been drilled in this type of material or otherwise restore it to the original condition (like the hole had never been drilled) short of actually replacing the countertop?  If so, how?  If not, what's the best and closest the achieving that?

Update: To answer some of the questions in the comments, it's a hole for an RO spigot (technically the supply line to the spigot).  I don't know the diameter exactly as I haven't messed with the spigot and can't see the hole without doing so.  You can't see the hole because it's covered up by the base of the spigot.  We basically have two options: to leave the RO unit behind (remain installed), or "restore the countertop to how it was before the RO was installed".  The latter would basically entail "filling" in the hole.  I'm putting quotes around "fill" because I don't know if filling is the right procedure or if it's even possible.  Putting something like a plug or stopper isn't an acceptable solution (this is for a rental and those were the options we were given).

Comment: That is a "quartz" countertop.  It's a man-made product with a mixture of quartz aggregate and a binding agent like cement.  Filling a hole is easy, you can use any number of products.  But making it difficult to see is another story.  If appearance is important you might want to contact a local company that specializes in this product.

Comment: @jwh20 is that likely to be an expensive fix (e.g. $100 or more)?

Comment: I can't say, lots of variables and also local market conditions to consider.  Call around and see if you can get anyone to come look at it and give you an estimate.

Comment: Why is "fill" in quotes? Do you mean something other than fill? Who are you quoting? Why doesn't your photo show the hole?

Comment: What size hole? 1/8” is a lot different to 4”...

Comment: If the hole was intentionally drilled for a water line or electrical but presently it's not being used, then you might not want to permanently fill the hole. Just put a stopper in it.  There are stoppers in plastic and stainless steel that would fit and prevent things from falling in.